# How does pytorch compute derivatives for simple functions?

Tags: python, pytorch, autodiff

When we talk about the auto-differentiation in the pytorch, we are usually presented a graphical structures of tensors based on their formulas, and pytorch will compute the gradients by tracing down the graphical tree using chain rules. However, I want to know what will happen at the leaf nodes? Does pytorch hardcode a whole list of basic functions with their analytical derivatives, or does it compute the gradients using numerical methods? A quick example:

```py
import torch

def f(x):
    return x ** 2
x = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
y = f(x)
y.backward()
print(x.grad) # 2.0
```

In this example, does pytorch compute the derivative by $$ (x^2)' = 2x = 2 * 1 = 2 $$, or does pytorch compute in a way similar to $$ (1.00001^2 - 1^2) / (1.000001 - 1) ~ 2 $$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: The first. See `autograd` (automatic differentiation backend for pytorch). I've been meaning to get through these [slides](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/slides/lec10.pdf) and these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc421_2019/readings/L06%20Automatic%20Differentiation.pdf) and also this ["Automatic differentiation for dummies" presentation by Simon Peyton Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtnkqIsfNQc)...

Comment: The second method you mention would probably not be a good idea for a deeper network since there's a ton of floating point error that you'd run into, which I presume would be akin to the vanishing gradients problem but worse.

Comment: So the developers of pytorch would have to hard-code the derivative of a lot of simple functions?

Comment: For functions like `f(x) = x**2`, you can just use rules. CAS like Maple (or even [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)) allow you to do symbolic differentiation on functions R -> R^n. How do *you* do differentiation? Do you use a table of rules that you've memorized? Or do you use complicated arguments with epsilons and deltas? (I wonder if CASes can handle those too...) For R^m -> R^n, which autodiff deals with, we can also have a [table of derivatives like this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5c9918e757b019564e74ae6f676cacfe70a87afd/tools/autograd/derivatives.yaml#L805).

Comment: And here's the [power rule](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/80d5b3785b88f83eb598e393d0137f045b979c4b/tools/autograd/templates/Functions.cpp#L158), probably hardcoded in C++ for performance reasons.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

See this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05767.pdf) for exact answer, specifically section 2.1 or figure 2.

In short, PyTorch has a list of basic functions and the expression of their derivatives. So, what is done in your case (y =x*x), is evaluating $$ y' = 2*x $$.

The numerical method you mentioned is called numerical differentiation or finite differences, and it is an approximation of the derivative. But it is not what PyTorch does.